# cowbuilder --create --distribution lucid fails

Tags: 10.04, packaging, pbuilder

I'm trying to create a build environment for Lucid, and calling `cowbuilder --create --distribution lucid` fails with the messages below:

```
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg [189B]
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages
Fetched 189B in 0s (2376B/s)
Reading package lists...
I: Obtaining the cached apt archive contents
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
apt is already the newest version.
Package cowdancer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package cowdancer has no installation candidate
I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
I: unmounting proc filesystem
pbuilder create failed
  forking: rm -rf /opt/cowbuilder
```

Comment: What does your ~/.pbuilderrc contain?

Comment: @Daenyth Is that the *complete* output? If so, then the problem is that you don't have the Universe repository (which provides `cowdancer`) enabled for the build; see [John S. Gruber](http://askubuntu.com/users/63886/john-s-gruber)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/178392/22949).

Comment: @EliahKagan: It's not, as the complete output was very long. I'll pastebin it somewhere if it fails after trying John's suggestion

Comment: @JohnSGruber: Nothing. I'm trying your suggestion now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `~/.pbuilderrc`:

```
COMPONENTS="main universe multiverse restricted"
```

or, as SunSparc suggested, enter the command as follows:

```
COMPONENTS="main universe multiverse restricted" cowbuilder --create --distribution lucid
```

`cowbuilder` is in the universe component for lucid. I don't see the create operation trying to access universe in the output you included in your question.

The file `~/.pbuilderrc` can be set up to set many `pbuilder` options that are used for `cowbuilder` as well.

Comment: Thanks, that got me farther. Failed after that trying to hardlink across partitions, but I should be able to solve that. I'm not left with a good impression of the robustness of this tool right now, I have to say.

Comment: I run it with a .pbuilderrc I picked up from [here](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2010/04/29/%23ubuntu-devel.html) from about 22:00 and [here](https://friendpaste.com/70JKdZJe7XuxuXtDDDjdQ8), adding quantal, etc., as necessary. I often just use _pbuilder_ as the speed difference isn't much. Both really need a good .pbuilderrc, however.

Comment: @Daenyth, I think for the cowbuilder technique to work both the .cow base and the temporary build directory must be on the same partition. The hardlinks are required as part of the .cow trick.

Comment: @SunSparc, It was messed up as it was. Thanks for pointing that out with your edit suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

The critical error message (below) baffled me for a little bit until I walked through exactly what `cowbuilder` (and the underlying `pbuilder` tool) are trying to do.

```
Package cowdancer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

It is a confusing message because it only appears when executing `cowbuilder --create`.  In other words, when I invoke this command, it complains about missing a package *I already installed*.  Weird.

Here is the missing link: `cowbuilder`--and by extension, `pbuilder`--are trying to create a clean, minimal, chroot environment, inside which there are no extra packages installed.  Even though `cowbuilder` is already installed *outside* the chroot, it appears to want to be installed *inside* the chroot as well.  Inside and outside the chroot are totally different worlds.  Outside the chroot (the regular environment), your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is king.  But inside, it is a different set of rules.  The default `pbuilder` environment only includes the most critical and minimal repositories necessary for a base/clean install.

The accepted answer talks about adding the "COMPONENTS" argument and specifying some additional repositories.  It did not work for me.  I tried adding the COMPONENTS value to the `/etc/pbuilderrc` file, my local `.pbuilderrc` file, and also doing that on the command line as an environment variable.  No luck. I did find a few references that mentioned how the COMPONENTS argument is not supported for `cowbuilder`.

Finally, I stumbled upon [a blog post](http://filthypants.blogspot.com/2011/01/setting-up-pbuilder-to-act-like.html) that talked about adding a variable named `OTHERMIRROR` to the `/etc/pbuilderrc` file.  For me, I simply added the following:

```
OTHERMIRROR="deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main restricted universe multiverse | deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse | deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted universe multiverse | deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse"
```

[Note that you can update/change `saucy` to whatever  you would like (e.g. `trusty`, `raring`, `precise`, or even `wheezy` and `sid` provided you have the appropriate debian mirrors, etc.).

Then, I simply ran the following from the command line and everything was created successfully and I was able to proceed:

```
sudo cowbuilder --create  # defaults to using current distribution
```

Obviously you can change distributions using the "--distribution" command line argument.  It takes a few minutes to establish the initial environment, but once it is created, you can easily update the packages, etc. using `cowbuilder`.

The [cowbuilder page on the Debian website](https://wiki.debian.org/cowbuilder#Building_your_package_for_many_distributions_at_once) talks about creating an Ubuntu-specific cowbuilder. It mentions that `cowdancer` has been moved to the `universe` repository. They reference running the following command to build a cowbuilder environment on Ubuntu:

`DIST=trusty sudo cowbuilder --create --distribution trusty --components "main universe"`

The `--components="main universe"` flag is the critical piece to ensure the creation process has access to all the necessary repositories.

Comment: Thanks for this, the accepted answer did not work for me either, but this one did. I am using the saucy distribution as well.